# Unable to launch "https" mobile websites in emulator using selenium webdriver under proxy settings

Tags: java, android, ssl, selenium, proxy

Unable to launch "HTTPS" mobile sites, normal web sites in emulator using selenium webdriver.
What are the proxy settings to be used for opening these sites in Emulator. I am using windows XP

Please let me know how to set

1. proxy settings and
2. hOW TO handle SSL certificates using Android driver in selenium

The connection code is as follows

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();

caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(caps);

driver.get("https://www.xyz.co.in/");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: Have you read the manual? What have you tried ? and where is your code ?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor : updated the question with code